# Can I have prescription medications mailed or shipped to a USA resident staying in Canada?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, us-citizens, health, medical-tourism

My Mother in law who is 86 years old is staying with us from the USA, and the pharmacies through US Medicare fill her meds for a 30 day supply only.

How could we get her meds be sent from the US to Canada? Who or what entity could do this?

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/142110/can-an-american-visitor-in-canada-get-critical-medications-sent-from-home?rq=1